# Cant get drop down menu onn click of a button through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an iframe which has a settings button, whose button I have appended through a javascript like-

```
headerFuncPanel.append( "<div title='settings button' class='settingsImg window_icon_button no-draggable'></div>" );
```

Now, I have to add to it a [simple dropdown menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/) - so that onClick of the settings button, I get a dropdown menu.

I have to include the following bit of code in form of a menu-

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cheetos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I can insert/add this menu list in the append function or add the same list through

```
headerFuncPanel.children(".settingsImg").click(function() {};
```

How can I add the menu html through javascript?

Comment: @thecodeparadox - What you said is correct, but I want to append a whole code snippet contained within a div tag. Suppose I add <p>Something</p> inside the appended div tag here above, I get a text Something below the settings button. Now, in place of that if I want to place a whole list of dropdown menu which I mentioned, how do I do that through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

tried to add $() around the variable?

like:

```
$(headerFuncPanel.children(".settingsImg")).click(function() {};
```

or just add event after the .append mothod:

```
headerFuncPanel.append(...);
$('.settingsImg').click(...);
```